# Não consigo obter elementos de uma página com o Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Estou criando uma aplicação para baixar uma imagem do Instagram pela URL e estou utilizando o pacote [`puppeteer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) para realizar esta tarefa.

Dentro da chamada do método `evaluate` (método para rodar um código JS na página) eu tento obter e retornar um elemento de imagem.

O problema é que sempre que eu tento obter a imagem, eu acabo recebendo `null` como resultado. Veja o meu código abaixo:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/<image_code>/";

async function getImageFrom(url) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    const image = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector(".KL4Bh > img");
    });

    await browser.close();
    return image;
}

getImageFrom(url).then((image) => {
    console.log(image);
});
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Já tentei utilizar o `querySelectorAll` buscando apenas por elementos com a tag `<img>` mas ele também me retorna apenas um array vazio.

Edit: Eu não sei o que aconteceu, mas o método está retornando `undefined` agora.

Comment: Este seletor (`.KL4Bh > img`) não me parece muito confiável e duradouro... É bem típico do Facebook mudar esse tipo de seletor com uma certa frequência. Apesar disso, não creio que seja o problema... Além disso, o que seria `None`? :P

Comment: Ops, foi mal eu confundi `null` com `None` kkk (mania de Python xD). Bom se o Instagram faz isso eu não sei, mas eu testei pegar o elemento direto no console do navegador e funcionou. Além disso, eu também testei obter apenas os elementos de `<img>` como eu já havia dito na resposta e mesmo assim o `puppeteer` só retornava um array vazio.

Comment: Pelo o que pude ver aqui, parece que não é um problema com o Puppeteer. O Instagram insere a imagem via JavaScript. Se você tentar baixar o HTML usando alguma ferramenta como cURL, verá que o seletor que você informou não estará lá. Penso então que seja colocado via JavaScript. Eu não sei se o método `evaluate` espera que todos os JavaScripts da página sejam devidamente finalizados, mas pelo o que me parece não é o caso. Vale investigar isso.

Comment: Mas o objetivo do `puppeteer` até onde eu entendi é ser uma espécie de `selenium` onde ele renderiza a página para ser depois manipulada. Então mesmo que as imagens sejam adicionadas via JavaScript, o `puppeteer` deveria renderizar isto e me devolver os elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `evaluate` está retornando o valor `null` porque talvez o elemento não exista na página. Seja porque não foi carregado ainda ou porque ele realmente não existe na página atual mesmo tendo carregado todo o código JS.

A outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455798/157404) diz para definir o valor `"load"` para a opção `waitUntil`, porém isso é redundante já que segundo a [documentação](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framegotourl-options) dessa API, por padrão essa opção será `"load"`.

Ainda assim esse não é o problema principal do seu código. Mesmo que o elemento tenha carregado na página, o método [`evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevaluatepagefunction-args) deve retornar `undefined` se tudo correr bem. Isso porque você está tentando retornar um objeto não serializável.

Se o seu objetivo é apenas obter o atributo `src` ou outro desse elemento que retorne uma string ou um outro valor serializável, faça-o dentro do método e o retorne como no código abaixo:

```
const image = await page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector(".KL4Bh > img").src;
});
```

Se você precisar do elemento por inteiro e não apenas de um atributo ou simples valor, utilize o método [`waitForSelector`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectorselector-options) como é mostrado na outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455798/157404). O que esse método faz é esperar e retornar um elemento da página com o seletor que você definiu. Veja o código abaixo:

```
const image_element = await page.waitForSelector('.KL4Bh > img');
```

Este método irá retornar um objeto de [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). Para obter os atributos deste elemento, utilize o método `getProperty(attr)` que retorna um objeto de [`JSHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-jshandle).

Após ter obtido este objeto, utilize o método [`jsonValue()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue) para obter o valor do atributo.

```
const image_element = await page.waitForSelector('.KL4Bh > img');
const image_property = await image_element.getProperty("src");

const src = await image_property.jsonValue();
```

Lembre-se de que todas essas ações devem ser feitas com o `browser` aberto. Sendo assim, você não pode fechar o `browser` antes de obter a propriedade da imagem ou receberá um erro.

Answer (score 4):

**Você provavelmente NÃO** esta esperando o load completar ou pode ser que a forma como o instagram carregue seja dinamica e até depois do load, cada site faz de uma forma.

Troque isso:

```
const image = await page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector(".KL4Bh > img");
});
```

Por:

```
page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])
```

Para esperar o elemento "existir" e que já é uma função **nativa** (o evaluete seria JS dentro do webview gerado, o que é retrabalho desnecessário), exemplo:

```
page.waitForSelector('.KL4Bh > img');
```

Ou ao invés de trocar sete a propriedade `waitUntil` em `options`

```
page.goto(url[, options])
```

E nele aplicar o valor `networkidle2` (que seria como o load e também não há mais de 2 conexões de rede por pelo menos 500ms), exemplo:

```
await page.goto('https://site.com', { waitUntil: 'load' });
```

Comment: Como assim trocar o `goto`? Não é este método que faz abrir uma página por uma URL? Eu tentei utilizar o `waitForSelector` e ele ficou esperando por muito tempo até que chegou uma hora em que o método gerou um erro dizendo que o tempo de 30000ms tinha sido excedido. Também tentei utilizar a opção `waitUntil: 'load'` mas ainda assim não funcionou.

Comment: Guilherme, uma coisa que estou vendo agora é que o resultado do `evaluate` não é mais `null` e sim `undefined`. Eu não sei quando esse resultado mudou, mas agora é isso que ele devolve.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 não era trocar o goto, corrigi a resposta, mas de qualquer forma experimente trocar o evaluete por `page.waitForSelector` ... pois evaluete é pra executar um javascript e não tem pq fazer isto se já tem método nativo.

Comment: Este método funcionou, mas como posso obter os atributos do elemento como o `src` ? E se possível, poderia explicar na resposta o porquê da opção `waitUntil` não funcionar ? Eu gostaria de saber isso para caso eu precise executar o `evaluate` futuramente.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 pode ter sido algo que você fez de errado, não sei, pode ser que o instagram mesmo após o load ainda tenha que carregar algo ... afinal, cada site trabalha de um jeito e inventa a propria moda, mesmo que as vezes seja meio sem noção (não tenho como testar se é isso mesmo).... Pegar o SRC acho que deve ser algo como `const propertyHandle = await element.getProperty('src');`, o element é o valor retornado pelo `page.waitForSelector`

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme pela sua ajuda, sua resposta foi bastante esclarecedora. Eu consegui descobrir o real problema do código e coloquei a solução na minha resposta.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 e no que difere do que eu disse ? Você usou praticamente o `page.waitForSelector` que eu citei, na sua resposta você dá a entender que eu respondi algo errado sobre pegar o elemento, como se eu tivesse dito só pra pegar o SRC, sendo que isso eu nem falei na resposta, na verdade isso nem na sua pergunta é falado, é algo que vc trouxe depois nos comentários, DESCONTEXTUALIZANDO toda a pergunta, como pegar o "elemento inteiro" (o handler) eu respondi.

Comment: Não eu coloquei o `page.waitForSelector` como algo alternativo porque a pergunta era mais sobre o problema com o `evaluate`. A única parte na minha resposta que tem ligação com a sua é quando eu falo sobre a opção `waitUntil`, em momento nenhum disse ou quis dizer que sua resposta estava errada por pegar um elemento de forma X ou Y. E realmente a pergunta é sobre pegar um elemento inteiro e não apenas o `src`, e na minha resposta eu explico que pegar um elemento inteiro com o `evaluate` é errado e que pra isso se deve ser utilizado o `waitForSelector`.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, peço desculpa se pareceu que eu estava dizendo que sua resposta estava errada. Na minha resposta a solução final para obter um elemento por inteiro é a mesma que a sua resposta, mas na minha eu explico sobre a raiz do problema e dou detalhes sobre outras coisas. Levei horas atrás de horas vasculhando a internet inteira até encontrar um simples comentário no GitHub que me fez entender o problema de tudo.

Comment: A pergunta não falava de nada disso @JeanExtreme002, ai foi além, quase como uma pergunta camaleão. Respondi ao que foi perguntando e ajustei a parte que estava errada sobre o load. A resposta basicamente esta na parte que eu falei "Você provavelmente NÃO esta esperando o load completar" e no comentário e "afinal, cada site trabalha de um jeito e inventa a propria moda", não tem como dizer quando itens dinamicos vão carregar, pra isso o waitForSelector resolve